# Most space-saving encoding for storage?

Tags: optimization, encryption, encoding, storage, aes

I use AES-256 to encrypt files.  I then base64_encode the data for the file and push it to the server.  This is increasing the size of the file on average 133%.  Is there a way for me to send it from JS->Database, w/ AJAX, where there is minimal space increase from just the regular encryption?

Comment: As far as ASCII-safe encodings go, base64 is pretty darn efficient. The only common thing more efficient would be raw binary. I'm not sure how raw binary may be sent properly from JS though. Hope someone can answer that.

Comment: base64 is your best bet, you don't want to send raw data because it might get screwed by the browser. Base64 is the least size increase.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about transfer size then base64 is optimal (though potentially you can implement your own BASE95 or so encoding). If you care about storage size, you can decode base64 back into binary format and store binary data in BLOB fields, and if you need to send them back to the client, then encode them again.